# How to view photos from Mac on iPad

Tags: ipad, mac, photos

I have tons of photos on my mac (Lion) and an external harddrive. They are not organized using iphoto, just sitting in different folders.

I would like to be able to view them on my iPad 2. Ideally I would like to be able to "like" them, currently I'm using color labels in Finder.

If I could also view the videos I would be ecstatic ;-)

thanks!

Comment: Do you want to transfer the photos to your iPad or just access them remotely? Is there a special reason you don't use iPhoto?

Comment: Or a reason you don't use Aperture?

Comment: I don't want to transfer them. I might use iPhoto if there isn't a simple solution available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed [AirPhotoViewer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airphotoviewer/id524118762?ls=1&mt=8).

It lets you view photos from your PC on an iPad or iPhone over wifi without syncing them on the device.

Comment: Is there also an OS X version of your server available?

Comment: pretty cool. I would be nice to have a "like" feature that would add a label to the file on the mac

Comment: the os x version server is release now， thanks for your proposal :)